# Blender won't let me set the path to Mcell or Python

Tags: add-on, path, installation

[image: MCell addon in blender]

I'm getting an error that there's a file/permissions error while setting the path to blender. I was able to download mcell as a gz file. But it wouldn't let me map it. I was also unable to gunzip the file in terminal. It showed that the file exists but when I try to gunzip it an error message comes up. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image: terminal]

Comment: Looks like the gz file is in the Desktop folder, but your are running gunzip from your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra `.gz` extension in your `gunzip mcell-3-3_osx_intel.gz` command. It looks like `gunzip` is trying to find your file by appending a `.gz` extension after you specify the filename.

That being said, the permissions error you're getting is probably not the same thing that's preventing you from using `gunzip` in the terminal. You can actually change the permissions of the file using the `chmod` command, but it might be easier to just follow the [change file permissions instructions on a Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18894?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) that's a little less risky if you're not how to use `chmod` in the terminal just yet. Make sure you're setting the permissions to "Read & Write".